# Matlab figure and truncating data

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

*xlim* command changes the axis limit of the figure.
How can i also limit data that is contained by the figure?
Apparently, even though *xlim* is applied data is still there.

**Example:** let's say i have a data set of 5000 elements. but only 1500 elements are shown in a figure. when i save this figure, it will still contain data that is not shown in the figure.

The answer may be particularly useful for people working with [matlab2tikz](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz).

Comment: brush can do it. how about brushing via command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the data are still there. To remove data, use something like this:

```
>> plot(1:10,(1:10).^2); % just an example
>> h = get(gca,'Children');
>> x = get(h,'XData')

x =

     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10

>> y = get(h,'YData')

y =

     1     4     9    16    25    36    49    64    81   100

>> set(h,'XData',x(2:5), 'YData',y(2:5))
>> set(h,'XData',x(2:5), 'YData',y(2:5))
```